# How to read line by line and match text with next line?

Tags: scripts

read the files data line by line and match the line with the next line, if it matches then save that line in the uniqe.txt file.

Comment: sounds like `uniq -d input.txt output.txt` (only print duplicate lines, one for each group)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version/release ?

Comment: so if you were to have `Abcde x 3`, should result in two `Abcde` in unique.txt?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a simple `for-loop`

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t < text.txt
for ((a=0,b=1; $b<${#MAPFILE[@]}; a++,b++)); do
     [[ ${MAPFILE[$a]} = ${MAPFILE[$b]} ]] && echo ${MAPFILE[$a]}
done > unique.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if "successive duplicate lines" is a key issue for you. If not then you simply need the Linux command uniq to eliminate duplicate lines in the file with:

```
uniq -u inputfile.txt > uniqe.txt
```

If, however, you are only interested in eliminating successive duplicates you can use awk:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {a=$0; print}  a!=$0 {a=$0; print}' inputfile > uniqe.txt
```